# How to hide borders between rows in a html table and display only borders between columns using css

Tags: html, css

I have an simple html table where I want to only display the borders between columns and hide the borders between rows. I tried the code below but it did not achieve what I was after.

I have also used `border-collapse : collapse` in css, but it didn't seem to work.

```css
table td, table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#items { clear: both; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee;   }
#items textarea { width: 300px; height: 50px; }

 #items,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table id="items">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Slno</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Description of Goods</th>
            <th style="width:120px;">Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>S1</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>S2</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>S3</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you looking for

```css
table th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }
table td{ padding: 5px; }

#items { clear: both; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee;   }
#items textarea { width: 300px; height: 50px; }

 #items,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table id="items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Slno</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Description of Goods</th>
            <th style="width:120px;">Quantity</th>
            
            
       
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tbody">
        
        <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>S1</td>
                 <td>3</td>
          </tr>
    
         <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td>S2</td>
                 <td>5</td>
          </tr>
            
     <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>S3</td>
                 <td>5</td>
                 </tr>
      
      </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: if this is what you need please tick the answer as use full

Answer (score 0):

you made the th/td to have "border:1px solid black" but you only need border-right

```css
table td, table th {border-right: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#items { clear: both; margin: 30px 0 0 0; }
#items th { background: #eee;   }
#items textarea { width: 300px; height: 50px; }

 #items,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table id="items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Slno</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Description of Goods</th>
            <th style="width:120px;">Quantity</th>
            
            
       
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tbody">
        
        <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>S1</td>
                 <td>3</td>
          </tr>
    
         <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td>S2</td>
                 <td>5</td>
          </tr>
            
     <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>S3</td>
                 <td>5</td>
                 </tr>
      
      </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add border right only

```css
table td, table th { border-right: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }

#items { clear: both; margin: 30px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid black; }
#items th { background: #eee;   }
#items textarea { width: 300px; height: 50px; }

 #items,td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<table id="items">
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:100px;">Slno</th>
            <th style="width:300px;">Description of Goods</th>
            <th style="width:120px;">Quantity</th>
            
            
       
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="tbody">
        
        <tr>
                 <td>1</td>
                 <td>S1</td>
                 <td>3</td>
          </tr>
    
         <tr>
                 <td>2</td>
                 <td>S2</td>
                 <td>5</td>
          </tr>
            
     <tr>
                 <td>3</td>
                 <td>S3</td>
                 <td>5</td>
                 </tr>
      
      </tbody>
        </table>
```